# Programmatically embedding in navigation controller (Xcode 14.2, io2 16+)

Tags: ios, swift

I had a working program consisting basically of a table view controller embedded in a navigation controller, and I decided to try to get rid to some mysterious/obnoxious warnings that first appeared in iOS 16 ("UINavigationBar decoded as unlocked for UINavigationController, or navigationBar delegate set up incorrectly"). Following online suggestions, I got rid of the navigation controller on the storyboard, and added some code to

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

// ViewController: UITableViewController is my VC class
        let viewController = ViewController()
        let navViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        window?.rootViewController = navViewController
    }
```

to embed it programmatically. The program would then crash with a message that stating that it could not deque a cell with identifier "itemCell", and "must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard". I solved that by adding the line

`self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "itemCell")`

in ViewDidLoad but I don't understand why this was necessary, since the identifier for the prototype cell is still there in the storyboard, just as it was before. Can someone illuminate me? Thanks.

Comment: I find it simpler to ignore the error about the UINavigationBar. One has to hope that Apple will fix their bug eventually.

Comment: No doubt it is simpler, but my question about the need to register the identifier in code when it is in the storyboard still stands.

Comment: @Torrontés - you *"added some code to..."* -- but you haven't shown us your code. It sounds like you are not instantiating your table view controller correctly, but we have no way of knowing without seeing your code.

Comment: It did not seem to me particularly relevant, but I have added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
   let viewController = ViewController()
   let navViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
   window?.rootViewController = navViewController
```

won't give you what you want.

In Storyboard, you have to give `ViewController` a `Storyboard ID` (such as "FirstViewController"), then instantiate it via code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController")
let navViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)
```

---

**Edit**

Assuming the view controller we ID as "FirstViewController" in Storyboard is a table view controller, and we want to load it as the "root" controller for a navigation controller, the full code block would be:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    window?.windowScene = windowScene

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController")
    let navViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: initialViewController)

    window?.rootViewController = navViewController

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. It worked. However it would seem it would seem the last line is unnecessary, and the one before does not need to be an assignment (the navViewController variable is not used anywhere). Am I wrong?

Comment: @Torrontés - see the **Edit** to my answer.